# Getting all item in DB

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to get an array of items from my DB using `gorm` it works fine and I am able to retrieve data but I am only getting one item in the array while there are more than that. here is my code to retrieve the array.

**Model.go**

```
type Address struct {
    ID        uuid.UUID  `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key;unique;not null"`
    Line      string     `gorm:"size:255;not null;column:line" json:"line"`
    Hostel    string     `gorm:"size:255;not null;column:hostel" json:"hostel"`
    CreatedAt time.Time  `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;column:createdAt" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt time.Time  `gorm:"default:CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;column:updatedAt" json:"updatedAt"`
    DeletedAt *time.Time `sql:"index;column:deletedAt" json:"deletedAt"`
}

type Addresses []Address
```

**Database.go**

```
type DbAddress struct {
    *model.Address
}

func (address *DbAddress) Get(db *gorm.DB) ([]model.Address, *errors.Error) {
    var err error
    addr := []model.Address{}
    err = db.Debug().Model(model.Address{}).Limit(100).Take(&addr).Error
    if gorm.IsRecordNotFoundError(err) {
        return nil, errors.NewNotFoundError(fmt.Sprintf("Address not found: %s", err.Error()))
    }
    if err != nil {
        return nil, errors.NewBadRequestError(fmt.Sprintf("error when trying to get Address: %s", err.Error()))
    }
    return addr, nil
}
```

**Services.go**

```
func GetAddress() (model.Addresses, *errors.Error) {
    result := database.DbAddress{Address: &model.Address{}}

    return result.Get(database.DB)
}
```

**Controller.go**

```
func GetAddress(c *gin.Context) {

    address, getErr := services.GetAddress()
    if getErr != nil {
        res.ResponseJSON(c, getErr.Status, nil, true, getErr.Message)
        return
    }
    res.ResponseJSON(c, http.StatusFound, address, false, "successfully got address data")
}
```

Comment: Use `Find` instead of `Take`.

Comment: @mkopriva, I'm thinking it would help if you make your comment an answer. Then King can accept it as the correct response.

Comment: @jcfollower as you wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Find`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Find) instead of [`Take`](https://godoc.org/github.com/jinzhu/gorm#DB.Take).

```
// Get first record, order by primary key
db.First(&user)
//// SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;

// Get one record, no specified order
db.Take(&user)
//// SELECT * FROM users LIMIT 1;

// Get last record, order by primary key
db.Last(&user)
//// SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;

// Get all records
db.Find(&users)
//// SELECT * FROM users;

// Get record with primary key (only works for integer primary key)
db.First(&user, 10)
//// SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = 10;
```

For more detials see: https://gorm.io/docs/query.html